# net5 threadPool GATE_THREAD_DELAY=500ms is wrong?

Tags: .net-core, threadpool

[image]

https://mattwarren.org/2017/04/13/The-CLR-Thread-Pool-Thread-Injection-Algorithm/

The .NET thread pool has an opportunity to inject threads every time a work item completes or at 500 millisecond intervals, whichever is shorter.

I test threadpool how to create new Threads.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp31
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount * 2; i++)
            {
                int id = i;
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.UtcNow:MM:ss.fff}: {id}");
                    tcs.Task.Wait();
                }));
            }

            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => tcs.SetResult()));
            PrintBusyThreads();
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine($"Done: {sw.Elapsed}");
        }

        static void PrintBusyThreads()
        {
            ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out var available, out _);
            ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out var max, out _);
            Console.WriteLine($"Busy Threads: {max - available}");
        }
    }
}
```

result:

```
Busy Threads: 8
09:08.583: 2
09:08.583: 4
09:08.583: 0
09:08.583: 5
09:08.583: 1
09:08.583: 6
09:08.583: 3
09:08.583: 7
09:09.582: 8
09:10.096: 9    ---
09:11.090: 10   ---1000ms why not 500ms？？
09:12.097: 11
09:13.089: 12
09:14.085: 13
09:15.096: 14
09:16.093: 15
Done: 00:00:08.5056871
```

Comment: Quirk of the threadpool manager, it at first waits 1 second to add *two* threads.  So 500 msec on average.  Its behavior just isn't that simple to reverse-engineer in general, at v4.0 it started using a self-tuning feedback loop.  A video about that is [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/shows/going+deep/erika-parsons-and-eric-eilebrecht--clr-4-inside-the-new-threadpool/).

Comment: @HansPassant this video is not available anymore. Here is a working link: https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/7280/04a634c0-0702-41cc-84a5-673c57d27280/Erika-Parsons-and-Eric-Eilebrecht--CLR-4-Inside-t_high.mp4